# ScrollView with Button

Tags: android, android-layout

I need result as this.

[image]

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/background_water"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include layout="@layout/finish_order_content"/>

        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sendOrder"
                    android:text="Оформить заказ"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_orange"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If ScrollView have a very long content then Button not show (I see only ScrollView). How to fix it?

Comment: you can put those into linear layouts and put weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below. Add `android:layout_above="@id/sendOrder"` to `ScrollView` to make it appear above the button and set its height `fill_parent` to fill the available space.

I'm not sure how `<include layout="@layout/background_water"/>` should work though as you haven't included it in the picture above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendOrder"
        android:text="Оформить заказ"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_orange"/>

    <include layout="@layout/background_water"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/sendOrder">

        <include layout="@layout/finish_order_content"/>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/background_water"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/finish_order_content"/>

    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendOrder"
        android:text="Оформить заказ"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_orange"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<include layout="@layout/background_water"/>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

  <include layout="@layout/finish_order_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/sendOrder"
                android:text="Оформить заказ"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_orange"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should work. I took the liberty of removing unnecessary Views. Not sure what background_water actually is, but if it is supposed to be used as background, just remove your include (and the android:layout_below part I added to your ScrollView), and use android:background on the main RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/background_water"
        android:id="@+id/include_layout"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendOrder"
        android:text="Оформить заказ"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_orange"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/sendOrder"
        android:layout_below="@id/include_layout">

        <include layout="@layout/finish_order_content"/>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this once ,put below code in xml file and view its preview .
I hope this will help u or atleast provides u a clue :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:background="#bb9789" >
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ff6790"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

value of

> `activity_vertical_margin`

is

> 16dip